# Is it possible to use "summarise" function by indicating a variable name in a bracket format?

Tags: r, function

I encountered a problem while programming a function to calculate weighted mean and standard deviation (error message: "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator").

For reproducible data,

```
set.seed(1)
sample<-as.data.frame(cbind(treat, weight))
treat<-c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10))
weight<-runif(20)
for (i in 1:nrow(sample)){
  sample$Y1[i]<-sample$treat[i] + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  sample$Y2[i]<- -sample$treat[i] + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
}
sample[3, "Y1"]<-NA
sample[5, "weight"]<-NA
sample[1, "weight"]<1000
```

And, the code for the function I am working is as follows.

```
func<-function(data.name, varlist, cond.var, relation, comp.value, gen.var){

   varlist.de<-unlist(strsplit(varlist, "[+]"))

 ### This is where I ecnountered the problem
  for (i in 1:nrow(data.name)){
   for (j in 1:(length(varlist.de)-2)){
      df_weighted<-
           data.name %>% 
                  summarise(weighted_mean = wt.mean(varlist.de[j+2], varlist.de[j+1]), 
                            weighted_sd = wt.sd(varlist.de[j+2], varlist.de[j+1]))
       }
    }

 return(data.name)

}

## I ran this code, then the error occured. 
func(data.name=sample, 
    varlist="treat+weight+Y1+Y2", 
    cond.var="weight", 
    relation = "!=", 
    comp.value = "NA", 
    My_New_Index1)
```

Specifically, "df_weighted<-data.name %>% group_by (TT) %>% summarise(weighted_mean = wt.mean(varlist.de[j+2], varlist.de[j+1]), weighted_sd = wt.sd(varlist.de[j+2], varlist.de[j+1]))" seems to generate the error message that "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Any suggestion to fix the error will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might try making a more minimal example that shows the issue without all the extra code so folks can quickly see the problem.  Without looking at things too closely, I often find `summarise_at()` a useful alternative when trying to program with `summarise()`.

Comment: Thanks! Following your advice, I just updated and shorten the question for others. I will also try your suggestion.